# How to add library on eclipse (python) ?

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, leap-motion

I am  developing `leap motion` with the help of `python`.

I have  downloaded `eclipse` and installed python plugin

Now I need to add `library` of leap motion , that is `LeapPython.pyd`

How to add this library on eclipse ?

Any help would be appreciated.  thank you

Comment: You could just add the .pyd to your source tree. Treat it like you would any other Python module (except modifying it, of course).

Comment: i do as you say and it's doesn't work and i have a problem like this 
https://developer.leapmotion.com/forums/forums/general-discussion/topics/trouble-installing-leap-module-in-python?page=1
(DLL load fail)
(dll load fail

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a **Python interpreter** and **Python libraries** to **PyDev** using the *PyDev-Interpreter-Preferences*. See [Getting Started](http://pydev.org/manual_101_root.html) in PyDev docs. This also assumes you have Python installed on your computer. And of course this assumes you have the [Leap Motion SDK](https://developer.leapmotion.com/) installed as well. [There are many SO questions related to Leap Motion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906305/how-do-i-start-writing-or-creating-an-app-for-leap-motion-python)

- Select **Window** from the menu bar at the top of the eclipse application. This opens a pull down menu.
- Select **Preferences** from the pull down menu. This opens the preferences window.
- Expand the **PyDev** arrow from the preferences tree along the left side of the preferences window.
- Select **Interpreter-Python** from the tree underneath PyDev. This displays the *Python Interpreters* configuration in the preferences window.
  [image: Python Interpreters configuration]
- If you have not done so already, click the **Auto Config** button, then **OK**, **OK**, &c. until your interpreter is configured.
- The bottom half of the *Python Interpreters* configuration allows you to select *Libraries* and other configuration options.
- If the folder containing **LeapPython.pyd** is not listed under *Libraries*, click the **New Folder** button, browse to the folder that containins it and click **OK**, **OK**, &c. until the folder is added to PyDev.

Comment: i'm try anyway and now my situation like this 
https://developer.leapmotion.com/forums/forums/general-discussion/topics/trouble-installing-leap-module-in-python?page=1

Comment: If you get this error `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` it is because the `*.dll` (could also be `*.pyd`) is incompatible with the target of the Python compilation that you have. What I mean is that if your Python installation was compiled with an x64 Windows os as its target, then all of your other extensions (e.g. `*.pyd`) must also have been compiled for the same target. Every target is different (windows-x86, windows-x64, macos-x86, macos-x64, linux-x86, ...). Your best bet is to add either Leap/LeapSDK/lib or Leap/LeapSDK/lib/x64 depending on your system

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone now i can compile successed .
i'm find how to solve this problem in here.
how to solve this problem is copy msvcp100.dll , msvcp100d.dll , msvcr100.dll  msvcpr100d.dll
into your project folder.

the problem is we call leap.py and leap.py call LeapPython.pyd and LeapPython.pyd must to use .dll file then we must to include 4 .dll file into my project

thank you everyone for answer

Comment: and it's no problem with pyhon27